if Angular signals are getter functions, why can we call them?
Take a look at the following commented code:
export class AppComponent {
  count = 0

  // our getter function
  get itscount() {
    return this.count
  }

  // setting a function equal to a getter function
  itsCount2 = this.itscount

  func() {
    // this.itsCount2() --> error
    this.itsCount2 // --> works fine 
  }
}

Now taking a look at Angular signals, which are also getter functions, we call them () which contradicts the previous example.
 count  = signal(0)

 func() {
  console.log(this.count) // returns the function reference
  console.log(this.count()) // returns 0
 }

Can anyone explain exactly why signals are getter functions if we call them like we call normal functions?
Any explanation would be great!

but in your class declaration count is not defined as a getter ...

Being used as a getter function does not make the function somehow special; it's just a function.

From documentation: You read a signal's value by calling its getter function, which allows Angular to track where the signal is used. It doesn't say that signal IS a getter, but only that signal HAS a getter function. More precisely, signal() returns getter function which you need to invoke to get current value of this particular signal.

Also checking the Angular docs, I think they're using the term "getter" in a more general sense, and not in references to get/set methods for an object property.

oh, that explains it. Thanks
